# What kind of cross validation to use

Tags: cross-validation

have a text dataset that consists of about 550 data points. I have doubts about what method will get me the best results.

1) I can split the dataset into training and testing, and further use a cross validation technique
  - what would be a better choice - Leave one out CV or K-fold CV?

2) Or instead, use nested CV instead of dividing my data into training and testing. Although I have never tried this method.

What would be the possible pros and cons of using the above-mentioned techniques? Or is there any better technique that I can use.